# Create singleton Queue Python

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, singleton

I'm creating a bunch of components in my project, each of them will be running in different threads.
They will communicate through `queue.Queue`. I would like to define all the different queues, which is classes that extends `queue.Queue`. Each of them will be singleton object, so the different components can just import that class, and get the instance.

I put everything in one file:

```
from queue import Queue

class QueueAudio(Queue):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Singleton Queue
        """
        if '_inst' not in vars(cls):
            cls._inst = object.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
            print('Creating {}'.format(cls.__name__))
        return cls._inst

class AudioInput(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = QueueAudio()
        print(self.queue)

    def run(self):
        self.queue.put('Input Audio')


class Interpretor(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = QueueAudio()
        print(self.queue)

    def run(self):
        print(self.queue.get())

audio = AudioInput()
audio.run()
interpretor = Interpretor()
interpretor.run()
```

In the constructor of the two components (`AudioInput` and `Interpretor`) I print the object, to make sure they are the same.
`AudioInput` put a string in the queue, and `Interpretor` reads it. However, the queue in `Interpretor` is always empty, making the program hangs forever.
Here's the output of the program:

```
Creating QueueAudio
<__main__.QueueAudio object at 0x103234c18>
<__main__.QueueAudio object at 0x103234c18>
```

Answer (score 2):

I solve my problem by using another method to define my class as a singleton :

```
class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]

class QueueAudio(Queue, metaclass=Singleton):
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

What's happening here is that after your `__new__` function returns the queue object, python implicitly calls `__init__` on it. This resets the queue and any items you've previously added are removed.

From the [docs on `__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__):

> If `__new__()` returns an instance of cls, then the new instance’s
>   `__init__()` method will be invoked [...]

Step by step, this is what happens:

```
audio = AudioInput()        # creates an empty queue
audio.run()                 # adds a value to the queue
interpretor = Interpretor() # implicit call to Queue.__init__ resets queue
interpretor.run()           # queue is empty, call blocks
```

---

This is a common problem when implementing singletons with `__new__`. You can work around this by using a metaclass, or by using a different function to get the queue singleton:

```
class QueueAudio(Queue):
    @classmethod
    def new(cls):
        if '_inst' not in vars(cls):
            cls._inst = cls()
            print('Creating {}'.format(cls.__name__))
        return cls._inst

# create a queue instance with "QueueAudio.new()"
```

Answer (score 0):

hi you can implement your singleton queue as this example

create a singleton decorator

```
# singleton.py
def singleton(class_):
     instances = {}

     def getinstance(*args, **kwargs):
         if class_ not in instances:
             instances[class_] = class_(*args, **kwargs)
         return instances[class_]

     return getinstance
```

know define your queue class with singleton decoration

```
 #singleton_queue.py
 import singleton.py
 import queue


 @singleton
 class MySingletonQueue:

      def __init__(self, **kwargs):
           self.q = queue.Queue()

      def put(self, data):
           self.q.put(data)
      ...
```

i hope that is helpful